# Immigration status of airline crew members on layover

Tags: united-states, immigration

Say an airline is flying internationally into the United States, with flight crew or cabin crew with citizenship in one of the countries designated in President Trump's Executive Order(s).

Would these crew members be allowed entry into the United States for lay-over?

(Please migrate as deemed suitable.)

Comment: Do they leave the airport during the lay-over?

Comment: They have to, because there's no airside transit in the US.

Comment: @mkennedy - I don't understand what you're saying.  In my experience it is possible in practice to transit the international terminal of an airport without ever passing through the host country's immigration control.

Comment: @feetwet  Have you experienced this at US airports?

Comment: @DJohnM - No, I've never arrived at a U.S. port without intending to enter the U.S.  And now that you mention it I'm not certain if I have ever arrived at an international airport where, upon deplaning, everyone wasn't directed straight through immigration....

Comment: @feetwet yep, exactly. The general topic of being able to stay airside in the US comes up a lot in [travel.se].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, airline crew members have to pass through US immigration on arrival, just like everyone else.  So they'd need a visa.  Airline crews are eligible for a [D visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/crewmember-visa.html) which is specifically for crew members on layovers.

Under the current version of the travel ban, citizens of the designated countries are allowed to enter if they already have a valid visa, which current crew members presumably would. However, if they don't, or if it expires, they might be refused a new visa.  This would effectively prevent them from working on flights to the US.

Comment: or if they were traveling on the passport of a country not on the list, that would be okay too

Comment: Link to D visa is 404.  Perhaps https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/crewmember-visa.html is an appropriate replacement.

Comment: @arp: Thanks, updated